# XSLT: replace XML value with current date and time

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML document:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <Elaborations>
        <Elaboration>
            <DateBegin>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateBegin>
            <DateEnd>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateEnd>
            <Result>12594</Result>
        </Elaboration>
        <Elaboration>
            <DateBegin>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateBegin>
            <DateEnd>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateEnd>
            <Result>12593</Result>
        </Elaboration>
        <Elaboration>
            <DateBegin>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateBegin>
            <DateEnd>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateEnd>
            <Result>12595</Result>
        </Elaboration>
        <Elaboration>
            <DateBegin>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateBegin>
            <DateEnd>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateEnd>
            <Result>29598</Result>
        </Elaboration>
        <Elaboration>
            <DateBegin>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateBegin>
            <DateEnd>2014-01-01T02:00:00.000+01:00</DateEnd>
            <Result>37583</Result>
        </Elaboration>
    </Elaborations>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to replace the values of the elements DateBegin and DateEnd with the current date and time, with XSLT.
I wrote the following transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="dateNow" select="current-dateTime()"/>
    <xsl:template match="DateBegin/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$dateNow"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="DateEnd/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$dateNow"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I'm getting a parse error on the XSLT document.
Where is the problem?

Comment: Please post the **exact** error you are getting.

Comment: There does not seem to be a problem with your code, it runs fine [here](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJ1). As Michael suggested, tell us what the error message was. Also, which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: I'm using the transformation in a Camel route. I get the following error: `javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot compile stylesheet` `Caused by: Error while checking the type of expression 'funcall(current-dateTime, [])'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved including camel-saxon in the classpath. This eventually enabled the use of the xslt 2.0 function (like current-dateTime).

Comment: Indeed, by default (without any external XSLT processor libraries), `javax.xml.transform` only supports XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have used the EXSLT date:date() extension function which Xalan supports.